# Converting callbacks with for loop and recursion to promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, es6-promise

I wrote a function running recursively to find out files whose name include given world. I do not understand how promises works and cannot find a way to write this function with promises despite trying hard.

I tried returning a promise inside findPath function but I couldn't use it since extractFiles calls findPath. I tried to create a list of promises and return all but couldn't succeed neither.

So how could I write these functions with promises?

```
const fs   = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


function findPath(targetPath, targetWord, done) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(targetPath)) return;

  fs.readdir(targetPath, (err, allPaths) => {
    if (err) done(err, null);

    for (aPath of allPaths) {
      aPath = path.join(targetPath, aPath);
      extractFiles(aPath, targetWord, done);
    }
  });

  function extractFiles(aPath, targetWord, done) {
    fs.lstat(aPath, (err, stat) => {
      if (err) done(err, null);

      if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        findPath(aPath, targetWord, done);
      }
      else if (aPath.indexOf(targetWord) >= 0) {
        let fileName = aPath.split('.')[0];
        done(null, fileName);
      }
    });
  }
}

findPath('../modules', 'routes', file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

Comment: are you writing this for practice or because you need it?

Comment: seems `done` could be called back more than once? is that correct?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon  for practice, the function works well with callbacks. I am trying to convert it to get promises. I watch most of lectures at youtube but they all give simple examples.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is

Comment: ok, that just complicates issues a little bit, ... so you say `I tried` ... what did you try?

Comment: Please show us your attempts at using promises.

Comment: I removed them but they are not correct attempts for sure. @Bergi

Comment: I removed them but they are not correct attempts for sure. @JaromandaX

Comment: obviously you removed them because there's no evidence in the code that you've tried anything to do with promises at all - so, as it stands now, it looks like you haven't even tried, and just want someone to write the code for you

Comment: my first step would be to make *promisified* versions of `readdir` and `lstat` - this makes writing the "promise" code much easier, and it's far easier to read too

Comment: Yes there is no evidence in the code since the code that I sent is working well. This is really not what I intent to. Thank you for your response @JaromandaX

Comment: Not sure I comprehend your last comment, so I posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to make the "core" code more readable, I'd promisify the fs functions

```
const promisify1p = fn => p1 => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(p1, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(result);
        }
    });
});
const readdirAsync = promisify1p(fs.readdir);
const lstatAsync = promisify1p(fs.lstat);
```

Then, just chain the promises as you would with any other promises

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function findPath(targetPath, targetWord) {
    const readPath = target => 
        readdirAsync(target)
        .then(allPaths => 
            Promise.all(allPaths.map(aPath => extractFiles(path.join(target, aPath))))
            .then(x => x.filter(x=>x)) // remove all the "false" entries - i.e. that don't match targetWord
            .then(x => [].concat.apply([], x)) // flatten the result
        );
    const extractFiles = aPath =>
        lstatAsync(aPath).then(stat => {
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                return readPath(aPath);
            } else if (aPath.includes(targetWord)) {
                return aPath.split('.')[0];
            }
            return false;
        });
    return readPath(targetPath);
}

findPath('../modules', 'routes')
.then(results => {
    // do things with the results - which is an array of files that contain the targetWord
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Not much to it at all.

Comment: Thank you again. I didn't know how to promisify core functionality. Does promisifying have any side effect?

Comment: in this case no - I can't speak for all cases :p bluebird promises has built in promisifaction which is probably far more robust than the code I presented here - note: you don't **need** to do it that way, I just find that moving *callback* code away from *promise* code makes it far easier to read :p

Comment: I find out that node 8 has a function for promisifiying: [util.promisify()](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html)

Comment: I know about that, but didn't include it because, well node 8 is about 2 days old :p